# How to connect to a headless Raspberry Pi A+?

Tags: wifi

I just got my A+. It does not have an Ethernet port.

I'm having trouble getting a network connection so I could to ssh into it.

Here is what I did so far:

1. Inserted the pre-installed NOOBS SD card
2. When first powered on, the LEDs were Green and Red
3. The LEDs after a power-cycle came up just Red
4. Inserted a USB WiFi dongle

Am I missing anything? What is the next thing that is supposed to happen?

Comment: I guess my problem is that NOOBS does not start-up with netwrok and sshd running. I'll need to connect an hdmi monitor and a keyboard and go thru the setup.

Answer (score 3):

Connect an HDMI and then power it on.

Navigate to your /etc/network/interfaces file and enter your wpa-ssid (or whatever wireless encryption you use) and your wpa-psk password. then `sudo shutdown -h now`

Insert your wifi dongle then power it on.

an example of an ssid and -psk

```
wpa-ssid "iLoveLamp"
wpa-psk "MyPassword"
```

Comment: @Aleksandr Levchuk - did you get it to work?

Comment: i got it to work thru a USB to Ethernet adapter, but I first needed to connect thru HDMI and keyboard. As soon as I connected the USB, eth0 showed up in `ifconfig`. Then I ran `dhclinet eth0` (i also enabled "Internet Sharing" on my Mac laptop). Now in `ifconfing` shows a working IP address :)

Answer (score 2):

I got my wireless adapter to work by following the instructions at the following blog:

[Automatically connect a Raspberry Pi to a Wifi network](http://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/)

On raspbian using a usb keyboard with the pi attached to an hdmi tv I edited the following file

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

use the following command to edit it from the command line

```
sudo vi /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

press `a` to enter append mode, then add the following to the end of the file

```
network={
ssid="YOUR_NETWORK_NAME"
psk="YOUR_NETWORK_PASSWORD"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

then shutdown

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

after that plug in the adapter and start up

Comment: to save and quit from vi press : then enter wq